# How do I overcome filenotfound error in os and shutil?

Tags: python, pytorch, operating-system, conv-neural-network, shutil

I have a train folder and test_folder with a subfolder of images in jpeg files and labels in txt files. The labels are 0, 1 and 2. I have created two new folders train_pytorch and test_pytorch. In the train and test folder, each image in one subfolder corresponds to the label in another folder. Etc. image_0000.jpg in image file = image_0000.txt in the label file . In the train_pytorch folder, I have subfolders 0, 1 and 2. These are all the different possible classes which the image_(number).txt files in the train_folder and test_folder label subfolders can have. I want to match the images with their labels and then move them into the new subfolders for both train_pytorch and test_pytorch so I can apply a pytorch imagefolder to it. How can I do this in python. I have created all the folders, I just need to move the files based on their labels (classes).

'''

```
import os
import shutil

# Define the paths of the original folders and the new folders
train_dir = r"C:\Users\rgs88\OneDrive\Documents\Semester 2 Data Science Masters\Computer Vision\CV2023_CW_Dataset\train"
test_dir = r"C:\Users\rgs88\OneDrive\Documents\Semester 2 Data Science Masters\Computer Vision\CV2023_CW_Dataset\test"
pytorch_train_dir = r"C:\Users\rgs88\OneDrive\Documents\Semester 2 Data Science Masters\Computer Vision\CV2023_CW_Dataset\train_pytorch"
pytorch_test_dir = r"C:\Users\rgs88\OneDrive\Documents\Semester 2 Data Science Masters\Computer Vision\CV2023_CW_Dataset\test_pytorch"

# Define the names of the subfolders representing each class
class_names = ["0", "1", "2"]
 
# Move the training files
for class_name in class_names:
    # Get the list of image and label files for the current class
    image_files = sorted(os.listdir(os.path.join(train_dir, r"images")))
    label_files = sorted(os.listdir(os.path.join(train_dir, r"labels")))

    # Create the subfolder for the current class in the pytorch train folder
    os.makedirs(os.path.join(pytorch_train_dir, class_name), exist_ok=True)

    # Move the image and label files for the current class to the corresponding subfolder
    for i, (image_file, label_file) in enumerate(zip(image_files, label_files)):
        # Check that the image and label files have the same number
        image_number = image_file.split("_")[1].split(".")[0]
        label_number = label_file.split("_")[1].split(".")[0]
        assert image_number == label_number, f"Image and label numbers do not match for file {i}"

        # Move the files to the corresponding subfolder
        if label_file.endswith(class_name + ".txt"):
            shutil.copyfile(os.path.join(train_dir, r"images", image_file),
                            os.path.join(pytorch_train_dir, class_name, image_file))
            shutil.copyfile(os.path.join(train_dir, r"labels", label_file),
                            os.path.join(pytorch_train_dir, class_name, label_file))
```

'''

I keep getting this error FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory:

'C:\Users\rgs88\OneDrive\Documents\Semester 2 Data Science Masters\Computer Vision\CV2023_CW_Dataset\train/images'

This happens for the these lines of code:

```
image_files = sorted(os.listdir(os.path.join(train_dir, r"images")))
label_files = sorted(os.listdir(os.path.join(train_dir, r"labels")))
```

I am not sure why a forward slash has been put in instead of backward slashes.

Comment: You're making us guess where this error happens.  Please update the question and add the **whole** error traceback message.

Comment: You're trying to list the contents of a directory that doesn't exist. Windows accepts both forward and backward slashes as file path separators. The problem is that the directory `C:\Users\rgs88\OneDrive\Documents\Semester 2 Data Science Masters\Computer Vision\CV2023_CW_Dataset\train\images` doesn't exist but you're asking for the contents of that directory via `os.listdir`.